# ¿Cómo indicar que operación hacer segun la inicial del producto?

Tags: sql, sap, hana

Es mi primera pregunta en el foro y espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo un query en el que muestro una lista de productos, esta lista tiene la cantidad, código, descripción y precio, los códigos empiezan con A y otros con E; los que empiezan con A me muestra el precio total pero los que empiezan con E me muestra el precio individual, necesito indicar a la consulta que los códigos que empiezan con E, multiplique el precio por la cantidad para obtener el precio total.

| Cantidad | Codigo | Descripcion | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A25 | CHILE | 30 |
| 4 | E15 | FRIJOL | 5 |

```
Select l."cant" as cantidad, l."cod" as codigo, l."desc" as descripcion, l."pre" as precio  from Pedidos."Lista" l
```

Se me ocurre hacer un `case when` junto a la sentencia like, pero no se como hacerlo para que busque los que empiezan con E y solamente multiplicar esos codigos.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Este sitio no es un foro, en el sentido tradicional, el recorrido te ayudará a conocer el funcionamiento de la plataforma, que está especializada en preguntas y respuestas técnicas de programación. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es con un `case` como bien dices, pero usas un `SUBSTRING`, cuyo argumentos son

- texto
- índice (comienza en 1 ...que bárbaro)
- largo

Entonces `SUBSTRING ( l.cod, 1, 1)` tomará el primer carácter de l.cod

```
Select 
  l."cant" as cantidad, 
  l."cod" as codigo, 
  l."desc" as descripcion, 
  CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING ( l.cod, 1, 1) = 'E' THEN l.pre * l.cant 
      ELSE l.pre
  END AS precio
from Pedidos."Lista" l
```

---

También es posible hacerlo con un `like` como bien intuías

```
Select 
  l."cant" as cantidad, 
  l."cod" as codigo, 
  l."desc" as descripcion, 
  CASE
      WHEN l.cod like 'E%' THEN l.pre * l.cant 
      ELSE l.pre
  END AS precio
from Pedidos."Lista" l
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono, investigando un poco sobre esa funcion para comprenderla mejor, encontre una pagina que adjunta funciones parecidas, la dejo por aca por si a alguien más le sirve.
https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mysqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=75&punto=25&inicio=#:~:text=%2D%20substring(cadena%2Cposicion)%3A,indicada%20por%20el%20segundo%20argumento.

Comment: @Emma La verdad que respondí bastante rápido, yo uso `SUBSTRING ` para casos parecidos. Pero ahora que leo tu comentario, me quedé pensado.....y claro que se puede hacer con un `like`, así que agregué dicho código a la respuesta